# AngularFire - Is that possible to specify a success callback to $firebase?

Tags: firebase, angularfire

Here is my `User` service:

```
angular.module('MyApp.services').service('User',
  function(FIREBASE_ROOT, $firebase, $timeout) {
    var users = $firebase(new Firebase(FIREBASE_ROOT + '/users'));

    console.log(users[21]); // => undefined

    $timeout(function() {
      console.log(users[21]); // => exists now!
    }, 2000);

    ...
  }
);
```

Why `users` is not immediately available?
Isn't `$firebase` blocking? If not, is that possible to specify a success callback? 
I couldn't find an answer in [the docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#constructor).

Answer (score 3):

$firebase is not blocking. It performs an asynchronous lookup by contacting the server.

Furthermore, the value returned is an object, not an array. In general, you're going to want to store your users using non-numeric ids for the reasons explained in [this article on array best practices](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-04-28-best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

To wait for the data to load, use the following approach.

Versions 0.7.1 and below:

```
var users = $firebase(URL);
users.$on('loaded', function() {
   console.log( users[21] );
});
```

Version 0.8 and above (releasing on July 30th):

```
var users = $firebase(URL).asArray();
users.loaded().then(function() {
   console.log( users[21] );
});
```

Having answered the question, let me point out that this is generally only useful for debugging. AngularFire bindings are made to just work on your behalf. You should not need to iterate them, wait for them to load, etc. Just push them into the scope and use them in the dom as appropriate; avoid worrying about these things at a controller level:

```
<li ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.$id}}: {{user.name}}</li>

<script>
  // in my controller:
  $scope.users = $firebase(URL);

  // or for 0.8 and above:
  // $scope.users = $firebase(URL).asArray();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It all makes sense now. The only question I have is: I use Simple Login which creates users with a numerical `$id`. I also have my own app `users` (which have a status for example). I thought it would be a good idea **to use the same ids**. But, you recommend to use non-numeric ids. Shall I prefix the `$id` I get from Simple Login, e.g. `"user21"` instead of `"21"`, or maybe you have a better suggestion?

Comment: Ideally, you could use the `uid` from simple login. However, the `id` *should* be okay. They will typically be around 6-8 digits, so they won't fall into the sequential algorithm (not having any near 0 or 1).

Comment: Thanks Kato! I didn't realize that Simple Login provides two types of ids. Can I ask why do you have both? Why not just `uid`?

Comment: If you are only utilizing a single provider, it can be a bit more aesthetic. It may also be useful to have the actual providers' ids vs one specific to Firebase.